# how to pass json data to page to page?

Tags: php, javascript, json, extjs, extjs4

I have a Extjs data store in home page and im getting data from store like this

```
var jsonData = Ext.encode(Ext.pluck(Ext.getStore('cart_store').data.items, 'data'));
```

which generate json data like

```
[{"id":24,"item_code":"TVSIV(B)"},{"id":25,"item_code":"TVSIV(A)"}]
```

any idea how to pass this data to another page like when you do a redirect?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your server supports PHP, you could also use a PHP Session.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php

Comment: How would he go from the client side to the PHP side? Surely he'd end up needing to post back/AJAX?

Answer (score 1):

You could use HTML5 local storage for this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage

Most modern browsers including IE7+ support it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate. any other ways that can compatible with every browser?

Comment: Stringify it and you can use a cookie, or you can AJAX back to your PHP and keep it there and have a new page request it back. There's tons of ways. I'd check out PersistJS as well.